# Wrong XPath for Package.appxmanifest (XML)

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I need change my app manifest in app building process and I try to use a MSBuildCommunityTasks for this. Target what I use looks like:

```
 <XmlUpdate
        Namespace=""
        XmlFileName="$(ManifestFile)"
        XPath="//Identity[@Version]/@Version"
        Value="$(App_Version).$(Revision)"/>
```

But when build process start I get only this:

```
Updating Xml Document "Package.appxmanifest". 0 node(s) selected for update.
```

My XPath is wrong. I try to use XPath real-time validators, but I can't choose right XPath expression for this file, I need some help for this.

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
  <Identity Name="1234567890" Publisher="12345678" Version="9.9.9.999" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="123456789" PhonePublisherId="1234567890" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Name</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>PlaceHolder</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="DT.PlaceHolder.WP.App">
      <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="PlaceHolder" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="PlaceHolder" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <m3:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png"></m3:DefaultTile>
        <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </m3:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This works for me:

```
<XmlUpdate
        Namespace=""
        XmlFileName="$(ManifestFile)"
        XPath="//*[local-name()='Identity']/@Version"
        Value="$(App_Version).$(Revision)"/>
```